HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is false after several minutes
I'm developing an API in asp.net  with EF core. For user management i use FirebaseAuth and here how i implement login/logout of user:
`public async Task<IResult> LogInUser(HttpContext context, string userCred, string password,
    LoginDeviceType deviceType)
{
    try
    {
        var user = await databaseUserProvider.GetUser(userCred);
        if (user == null)
            return Results.Problem(detail: "Cannot find user in database", statusCode: 500,
                title: "User not found");
        string userEmail = emailAttribute.IsValid(userCred) ? userCred : user.Email;

        var authLink = await firebaseAuthProvider.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(userEmail, password);

        await SignInUserV2(userCred, password, context);

        return Results.Ok(new { user.Id,user.DisplayName ,authLink.FirebaseToken });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Results.Problem(detail: ex.Message, statusCode: 500, title: "An error occurred     while logging in");

    }
}`    
`public async Task<IResult> LogOutUser(HttpContext context)
{
    await context.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    return Results.Ok("User has been logged out successfully.");
}    `

i use claims-based authentication in my project
`public async Task SignInUserV2(string username, string password, HttpContext httpContext)
{
    
    var claims = new List<Claim>
    {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, username),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "User") 
    };
    var claimsIdentity = new    ClaimsIdentity(
claims,
CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme); 
    var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);
    await httpContext.SignInAsync(
 CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, claimsPrincipal,
        new AuthenticationProperties
        {
            IsPersistent = true, 
            ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7) 
        });
}`

an this is how i check if the user authenticated:
`public override bool IsUserAuthorized(HttpContext httpContext)
{
    if (httpContext.User.Identity?.IsAuthenticated == true)
    {
       
        var username = httpContext.User.Identity.Name; 
        var roles = httpContext.User.FindAll(ClaimTypes.Role); 

        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        // User is not authenticated
        return false;
    }
 }`

but the problem is that after several minutes(~10-15) i logged in  all the requests that require authorized user returns 401Unauthoreized error. Also i created test request in which i put claims  info in response. This is the response right after authentication:
 `{
  "responseStatusCode": 200,
   "isAuthenticated": true,
   "userName": "myuser",
   "claims": [
    {
        "type": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name",
        "value": "myuser"
    },
    {
        "type": "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role",
        "value": "User"
    }
],
}`

and this after a few time:
` "responseStatusCode": 200,
"isAuthenticated": false,
"userName": null,
"claims": [],`

as you can see after few minutes user become unauthorized. Does anyone know why this happens and how to fix it?
Ive already tried to use SecurityStampValidatorOptions but it doesnt help:
services.Configure<SecurityStampValidatorOptions>(options => { options.ValidationInterval = TimeSpan.FromHours(10); });

fixed this problem by adding this line in services iniliatlization:
 services.AddDataProtection()
        .PersistKeysToDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>()  // Store keys in the database
        .SetDefaultKeyLifetime(TimeSpan.FromDays(90)); 

also updated my dbcontext and make new  migreations:
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext,IDataProtectionKeyContext
{
//other db logic
public DbSet<DataProtectionKey> DataProtectionKeys { get; set; }
}

